# How do you determine token type in Java?

Tags: java, stack, token, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to use StringTokenizer and populate 2 stacks with the elements inside the String input. I'm trying to use two if loops embedded in a while loop to populate the right type of token into their respective stacks. I am struggling with how to actually set up a conditional to determine the type. Here's what I have so far.

```
 Stack numbers = new Stack();
 Stack operators = new Stack();
 StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(expr, delimiters, true);

 while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
   if(token.nextElement() == ){

   }
   if(token.nextElement() == ){

   }
 }
```

Comment: 1. Don't call token.nextElement() more than once in the while loop body. 2. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: don't use `==` to compare strings, use `.equals(otherObject)` instead

Comment: Since it looks like you're new to this site, I'll point you to [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You basically have to click the green checkmark next to the bast answer to mark your question as resolved an to reward the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use == with strings. Please use .equals() instead.

The next problem is that the token you compare in the first condition is another than the one in the 2 condition. `token.nextToken()` gives returns the first token and also deletes it from the Tokenizer.

You could make a temporary variable which stores the first element. You can then use this one to compare it to something.

```
Stack numbers = new Stack();
Stack operators = new Stack();
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(expr, delimiters, true);

 while(token.hasMoreTokens()) {
   String tmp = token.nextElement()
   if(tmp.equals(...) ){

   }
   if(tmp.equals(...){

   }
}
```

Comment: okay i thought that the tokenizer just made the type whatever the compiler thinks that it is (ie. if they see 3 they assume int). thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

## The answer

The returned tokens are actually Strings, so you can do the usual stuff with them. I don't know what your exact requirements are but something like this should work:

```
List<String> operators = Arrays.asList("+", "-", "*", "/");
StringTokenizer token = ...;

while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
    String next = token.nextElement();
    if(operators.contains(next)){
        //operator
    }
    else if(next.matches("\\d+")){
        //number
    }
    else {
        //error?
    }
 }
```

First of all you should use a use a variable for the next token, nextElement() also deletes the token from the Tokenizer so you have to keep it somewhere. Then we can determine the type by comparing String, here I check if it's part of a list of predetermined operators and whether it matches the regex `\d+`, ie. whether it is a number.

## Deprecation

The [StringTokenizer JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) says it has been deprecated in favor of [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

So I would recommend against using this class.

Comment: this is part of an algorithm to solve mathematical expressions that are inputted from left to right (ignoring usual order of operations). thank you for your reply